# FaceBook Modal is not coming up

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

I am trying to use FaceBook Login through a modal. If I click on below button FaceBook Login Modal will come up.

```
<li>
   <a href="#sign-in-dialog" class="login sign-btn" title="Sign In">Sign In</a>
</li>
```

My Modal HTML code is like below

```
<div id="sign-in-dialog" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
   //  more code
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap4 like below

```
<link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2):

If `bootstrap` file is already **saved** on your **computer**. then i think your link is maybe wrong check for it.

**These are online Bootstrap 4 Links:-**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```